# Making PHP While Loops Dynamic

Tags: php, mysql

I write at least a billion PHP while loops a day. Does anybody know of any cool techniques for making the following code dynamic using PHP functions or objects?

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT blah FROM blah_blah");       
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
//execute statements here
}
```

Comment: What you are talking about? :?

Comment: Do you mean something like, applyWhileLoop($results, $statements_to_execute)...? If this case... you mean functional as opposed to dynamic.

Comment: public function blah($rows, $table. $blah) {
$results = mysql_query("SELECT".$rows." FROM".$table."");       
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
echo $blah;
}
}
Something like this, but with a little more leeway.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby What does "more leeway" mean? What's wrong with the code you wrote?

Comment: It seems restricted. What if I want to run a more advanced SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Bryan's comment, you can do something like this as of PHP 5.3+:

```
function applyStatements($query, $callback) {
    $result = array();
    $mysqlResult = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlResult)) {
        $result[] = $callback($row);
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = applyStatements('SELECT foo FROM bar', function ($row) {
    return $row['baz'];
});
```

(Needs additional error handling in case of MySQL failure etc.)

Comment: I was going to answer exactly that way too! :)